# Legal advice regarding return travel to Turkey

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, international-travel, turkey

I was a student in Turkey, and I was renting a place with a couple of uni friends, all bills and the contract was under my name and my Foreign ID number issued by the Turkish authorities (residence permit). The complex had an administrative office, where we paid our monthly dues. I discovered that I was listed as owner of the house (property owner's way of tax evasion).

I left in 2016, intending never return there anytime soon, and my friends continued living in that house, paying the rent and the bills, etc. They left that house this week, and I got a message from the complex administration stating that I have an amount to pay as overdue, under my name (which is written incorrectly), and passport number.

Now I am in the process of passport renewal, thus my passport name will be corrected, and the passport number will change.

I am planning to visit soon, using the new passport (corrected name, new passport number), with an expired residence permit.

Will it be safe to visit or will I be stopped upon exiting the country and asked to pay the overdue amount?

Comment: Sorry, but we can't give you legal advice: you need to talk to a lawyer about that.